# How to validate signature with phpseclib, in a XML signature message?

Tags: php, encryption, sign, xml-signature, phpseclib

I tested the final XML signature file and it sends, "invalid signatures", why?
Information:
I have prepared this inf. to be signed with XML signature:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><SolicitudRegistro
    xmlns="http://www.cie.mx/SCG/Inilidad" IdMensaje="f2-8505d81914c">
<FechaEnvio>2013-02-26T21:08:36</FechaEnvio>
<Registrante EndPoint="https://200.34.175.46:443/InteropOPE
    /MensajeidadService"  Nombre="Instigua" NombreCorto="IMTA" URI="op.mx">
<DatosDeContacto AreaOficina="Informatica" 
    CorreoElect="req@tc.ia.mx" Nombre="Rafadina" Puesto="Subdirector nicaciones" >
<Telefonos>
<Telefono Extension=" " NumeroTelefonico="7773293644" />
</Telefonos>
</DatosDeContacto>
<CertificadoInstancia>MIIFETCCA/mgAwIBAgIUMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMD CERTIFICATE 
    WITH SENDER'S PUBLIC KEY=</CertificadoInstancia>
</Registrante>
<Reto>
<CadenaCifrada>Ln0BAsnwrNg6IzjW7hk2c/Nxx/x3LZ STRING ENCRYPTED 
    WITH PRIVATE KEY SO RECEIVER CAN AUTHENTICATE SOURCE WITH SENDER'S CERTIFICATE=
</CadenaCifrada>
</Reto>
</SolicitudRegistro>
```

So I stored all this in file results.xml, then I sign it with phpseclib functions, the code is:

```
<?php
require('xmlseclibs.php');
if (file_exists('./firmas/sign-basic-test_mio.xml')) {
    unlink('./firmas/sign-basic-test_mio.xml');
}
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('./firmas/results.xml');
$objDSig = new XMLSecurityDSig();
$objDSig->setCanonicalMethod(XMLSecurityDSig::C14N);
$objDSig->addReference($doc, XMLSecurityDSig::SHA1,
    array('http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature',
    array('http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116' =>
    array("query" => "ancestor-or-self::*[local-
    name()='SolicitudRegistro']"))),array("force_uri"=>true));
$objKey = new XMLSecurityKey(XMLSecurityKey::RSA_SHA1, array('type'=>'private'));
/* load private key */
$objKey->loadKey('i.pem', TRUE);
$objDSig->sign($objKey);
/* Add associated public key */
$objDSig->add509Cert(file_get_contents('instancia_imta_ope.crt'));
$objDSig->appendSignature($doc->documentElement);
$doc->save('./firmas/sign-basic-test_mio.xml');
$sign_output = file_get_contents('./firmas/sign-basic-test_mio.xml');
$sign_output_def = file_get_contents('./firmas/sign-basic-test_mio.res');
if ($sign_output != $sign_output_def) {
    echo "NOT THE SAME";
}
echo "DONE";
?>
```

This gives a complete XML signature that looks like (truncated some encrypted text):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<SolicitudRegistro xmlns="http://www.cb.mx/SCG/Interlidad"
    IdMensaje="f2e140eb-2b09-44ab-8504-87b25d81914c">
<FechaEnvio>2013-02-26T21:08:36</FechaEnvio>
<Registrante EndPoint="https://200.34.175.46:443/InteropOPE.....
<DatosDeContacto AreaOficina="Informatica" CorreoElectronico.....
<Telefonos>
<Telefono Extension=" " NumeroTelefonico="7773293644"/>
</Telefonos>
</DatosDeContacto>
<CertificadoInstancia>MIIFETCCA/mgAwIBAgIUMDAwMDY....=</CertificadoInstancia>
</Registrante>
<Reto>
<CadenaCifrada>Ln0BAsnwrNg6IzjW7hk.....</CadenaCifrada>
</Reto>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod
    Algorithm="http://ww.org/TR/2001 /REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
   <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
   <ds:Reference URI=""><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.
   w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><ds:Transform
   Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
  <ds:XPath>ancestor-or-self::*[local-name()='SolicitudRegistro']</ds:XPath>
  </ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod
  Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09 /xmldsig#sha1"
  /><ds:DigestValue>GogFeLcUThvfAeyNrDBroTQaGhA=</ds:DigestValue>
 </ds:Reference>
 </ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>N+Btck0X9H81ZUcmrIK3h7LR2CtA86BPaBFE=
</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>MIIFETCCA/mgAwIB.....=</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
```

All this for 1 question,
do you know any example how to validate this signature using PHPSECLIB?
Or another library?
the testing page that shows invalid signatures is:
https://ope.gob.mx/BrokerInteropQA/Diagnostico/default.aspx

thanks, 
I apologize for so much information, but I tried to be clear in my doubt
mario

Comment: Could you please take a look at the FAQ, respond to comments and accept answers?\

Answer (score 4):

I'd use [xmlseclibs](https://code.google.com/p/xmlseclibs/) ([author-blog](http://www.cdatazone.org/)). Right now that's probably using the [`openssl_*` functions](http://php.net/book.openssl) but it could probably be rewritten to use [*phpseclib*](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).

The reason phpseclib isn't sufficient is because, for XML Signatures, you need the [XML to be canonicalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_XML).  and    are gonna be interpreted the same way but *phpseclib* doesn't know that. To *phpseclib* it's just a text string and treated as text strings they're both different. But treated as XML strings they're not.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following with xmlseclibs, but it sent me FAILURE !!!!, what could be wrong?

```
<?php
require('xmlseclibs.php');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$arTests = array('SIGN_TEST'=>'./firmas/sign-basic-test_mio.xml');
foreach ($arTests AS $testName=>$testFile) {
    $doc->load($testFile);
    $objXMLSecDSig = new XMLSecurityDSig();
    $objDSig = $objXMLSecDSig->locateSignature($doc);
    if (! $objDSig) {
    throw new Exception("Cannot locate Signature Node");
    }
$objXMLSecDSig->canonicalizeSignedInfo();
$objXMLSecDSig->idKeys = array('wsu:Id');
$objXMLSecDSig->idNS = array('wsu'=>'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis- 
    200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd');
$retVal = $objXMLSecDSig->validateReference();
if (! $retVal) {
    throw new Exception("Reference Validation Failed");
}
$objKey = $objXMLSecDSig->locateKey();
if (! $objKey ) {
    throw new Exception("We have no idea about the key");
}
$key = NULL;
$objKeyInfo = XMLSecEnc::staticLocateKeyInfo($objKey, $objDSig);
if (! $objKeyInfo->key && empty($key)) {
    $objKey->loadKey('i.pem', TRUE);
}
if ($objXMLSecDSig->verify($objKey)) {
    print "Signature validateddd!";
} else {
    print "Failure!!!!!!!!";
}
print "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: After the previous result, I would try phpseclib, but you said is not sufficient, so maybe you see what is missing or wrong in this validation code, thanks neubert

Comment: Note: sign-basic-test_mio.xml has the complete XML signature and i.pem is the private key